# How to estimate an IV Probit when using complex sample survey design ("survey" package) in R?

Tags: r, survey

I am working with a brazilian survey called PNAD and I need to estimate a PROBIT model with an instrumental variable (IVPROBIT).
However, I have used the "survey" package to specify the complex survey design and, therefore, I believe I am restricted to using functions from the "survey" package to estimate models. That said, how do I estimate an IV Probit considering I need to stick to my complex survey design specification (an object of class `survey.design`).
Therefore, how do I estimate an IV Probit considering all that was said above?

Since this is a two stage Probit, I did try to estimate both stages separately using `svyglm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, design = survey_design, family = binomial(link = "probit"))` for each stage, but I was told that it isn't as precise and that the Std. Error on the second stage would be wrongly estimated.

Comment: I don't know how to do this, so there's reasonable chance no-one does.  If you can find code to do the estimation with any sort of weights, the `withReplicates` function will let you do it with sampling weights.